# Como passar dado de uma tela para outra após função executada

Tags: swift-3

Após executar a func de salvar dados no banco, como posso enviar o idcep para outra tela/ViewController?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
@IBAction func salvarEndereco(_ sender: Any) {

    let parameters = [
        "cep": cepTextField.text!,
        "logradouro": logradouroTextField.text!,
        "bairro": bairroTextField.text!,
        "cidade": cidadeTextField.text!,
        "uf": estadoTextField.text!,
        "opcao": NSNumber(value: 1)] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/salvaEndereco.php")! //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
        //print("Dados", request) dados salvos vindo no request

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        print("Data: ", data)

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Em que parte desse código eu posso enviar o dado para outra?
O dados que quero enviar está no objeto data

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, bom dia,

Na verdade a responsabilidade pela requisição não deveria ser da sua viewController, porém, como você fez assim, acredito que seria bom vc criar um segue para a próxima viewController e no prepareForSegue vc passa o objeto.

Exemplo:

```
//Faz a chamada da outra viewController
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier do segue", sender: nil)
//Implementa a função do prepareSegue

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let proximaViewController = segue.destination as? ProximaViewController, segue.identifier == "identifier do segue"{
        proximaViewController.objeto = objetoQueVaiPassar
    }
}
```